# ORA-00984: column not allowed here while inserting data excluding the sequence trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

First I created table using this query:-

```
CREATE TABLE mca (
    id number not null primary key,
    name varchar2(200) not null,
    password varchar2(200) not null,
    email varchar2(200) not null,
    country varchar2(200) not null
)
```

Then I created sequence using the query:-

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq
 START WITH     1
 INCREMENT BY   1
```

Then I created Trigger so that id would auto increment during insertion:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MCA_TRIG
BEFORE INSERT ON MCA
FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
  :new.ID := ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

**Now when I'm trying to insert data, I'm getting error:-**

```
insert into mca (name,password,email,country) values ("Ankit", "Ankit123", "ankit@gmail.com","India");
```

Error- Column not allowed here.

**If I try this query:-**

```
insert into mca values ("Ankit", "Ankit123", "ankit@gmail.com","India");
```

Error- Not enough Values.

**I also tried to add id_sec.NEXTVAL in Values still getting column not allowed error.**

**NOTE- I am using Oracle 11g**

Comment: You are using double quotes instead of single quotes to represent literal values in your insert statement. Double quotes are only for specifying object or column names (when they need to be case sensitive or include other things that require quoting)

Comment: In addition to your double-quote issue, your trigger is faulty.  If you are going to use a sequence to populate a column, then you need to use it _every_ time,  If you sometimes allow it to be supplied, then you _WILL_ eventually hit a case where the value returned by the sequence is the same as one the was manually supplied and accepted.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It worked !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error- Column not allowed here.

You also need to use `'` single quotes for string literals (double quotes are used to signify case-sensitive identifiers, such as column names).

> Error- Not enough Values.

You have 5 columns but only 4 values in the `INSERT` statement and you haven't told the SQL parser which 4 columns you want to use. Give the column names.

So your statement should be:

```sql
insert into mca (name,password,email,country)
values ('Ankit', 'Ankit123', 'ankit@gmail.com','India');
```

*(Don't store the password as plain text. At the very least, store a one-way hash of it.)*

```sql
CREATE TABLE mca (
    id            NUMBER
                  -- NOT NULL           Not necessary for a primary key
                  CONSTRAINT mca__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
    name          varchar2(200) not null,
    password_hash varchar2(200) not null,
    password_salt varchar2(200) not null,
    email         varchar2(200) not null,
    country       varchar2(200) not null
);

CREATE SEQUENCE mca_id_seq;
```

And the triggers:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER mca_id
BEFORE INSERT ON MCA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.ID := mca_id_seq.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```

and:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER mca_hash_and_salt_password
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON MCA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.PASSWORD_HASH = :old.PASSWORD_HASH THEN
    -- Assume things haven't changed (The chances of a hash collision are vanishingly small).
    -- Make sure the old salt is not replaced if the password hash hasn't changed.
    :new.PASSWORD_SALT := :old.PASSWORD_SALT;
  ELSE
    -- Regenerate a new salt and hash the password.
    :new.PASSWORD_SALT := DBMS_RANDOM.STRING( 'P', FLOOR( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 40, 61 ) ) );
    SELECT STANDARD_HASH ( :new.PASSWORD_SALT || :new.PASSWORD_HASH, 'SHA512' )
    INTO   :new.PASSWORD_HASH
    FROM   DUAL;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
insert into mca (
  name,
  password_hash,
  email,
  country
) values (
  'Ankit',
  'Ankit123',
  'ankit@gmail.com',
  'India'
);
```

Gives the value in the table:

> ```
> ID | NAME  | EMAIL           | COUNTRY | PASSWORD_SALT                                           | PASSWORD_HASH                                                                                                                   
> -: | :---- | :-------------- | :------ | :------------------------------------------------------ | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | Ankit | ankit@gmail.com | India   | &!WAMmJkSpQgUD(BS~ub+2*Yk]]bT_IA* xm|:.[oE\z.)*u*HAEV*B | 82CF5AE586605968DA320A64E7DDC7154FD11BEF0E0680350CA9BF5D5BEEB65D8D05FF50B8DC061E698A94FDAED46A73BAD826303C90AB49352E869931DCF04E
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=851e5cc415b09020cf36d819286dd50b)*

Comment: OP says he's on 11g, identity columns were only added later.

Comment: Can you please explain this part - :new.PASSWORD_SALT := DBMS_RANDOM.STRING( 'P', FLOOR( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 40, 61 ) ) );
    SELECT STANDARD_HASH ( :new.PASSWORD_SALT || :new.PASSWORD_HASH, 'SHA512' )

Comment: [`DBMS_RANDOM.STRING`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_random.htm#TTPLP71243) generates a random string, the `'P'` option is for printable characters and the second option is for the length (in this case a random value from 40 to 60 characters). It then get assigned to the `PASSWORD_SALT` column. `STANDARD_HASH` generate a hash of the concatenation of the password and the salt using the `SHA512` hash algorithm. This is a one-way hash so you hope that it is prohibitively expensive for anyone to work out what the user's password is and the salt is there so that if two users have ...

Comment: ... the same password then they will get different hash values and so that attackers cannot use a rainbow table of common passwords (which they may be able to do if you use the hash without the salt). You can easily check if the user has the correct password when they use it to access your service by just going through the same process of concatenating with the stored `password_salt` and then hashing with the same `SHA512` algorithm and then comparing the hash to the stored hash. There is an example of this in the linked db<>fiddle.