# Oracle SQL Insert Trigger to Hash Password is not working (Issue with CHAR)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to build a insert trigger to hash a string into a SH-256 password:

```sql
DROP TABLE client;

CREATE TABLE client (
    id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    password CHAR(64) NOT NULL
);


-- Add Insert Trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER client_hash_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON client
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    password_hash CHAR(64);
BEGIN
    SELECT STANDARD_HASH(:NEW.password, 'SHA256') INTO password_hash FROM dual;
    :NEW.password := password_hash;
END;


INSERT INTO client VALUES (DEFAULT, 'BruteForce');
```

When I run the SQL I'll get a wrong hash in my table. When I change booth char to varchar it's working. When I put the STANDARD_HASH directly into the insert line it working as well. Where is the issue?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions183.htm#SQLRF55647) says that `standard_hash()` "returns a `RAW` value". So you should also use `raw` or a compatible data type. `char` doesn't seem to fit here, unless I'm missing something. (Here `char` isn't like the `char` in C where it's essentially just a byte.)

Comment: Okay but when I remove the trigger and hardcode the STANDARD_HASH: `INSERT INTO client VALUES (DEFAULT, STANDARD_HASH('BruteForce', 'SHA256'));` It can be inserted into char. Why is that? Auto conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TL;DR] Use `STANDARD_HASH( RTRIM( :new.PASSWORD ), 'SHA256' )` as you want to generate the password on `'BruteForce'` and not `'BruteForce      '` (etc.) padded with white-space to a length of 64 characters (which is what using `CHAR(64)` would give you).

---

If you don't want to use a salt (which you should be using in this day-and-age) then just right-trim the password to get rid of the trailing white-space that the `CHAR` data type have padded the string with:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER client_hash_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON client
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT STANDARD_HASH( RTRIM( :new.PASSWORD ), 'SHA256' )
  INTO   :new.PASSWORD
  FROM   DUAL;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
CREATE TABLE client (
    id            NUMBER(10,0)
                  GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                  CONSTRAINT client__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
    password      CHAR(64)
                  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO client (id, password) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'BruteForce');
```

Will output:

```sql
SELECT id, password FROM client;
```

> ```
> ID | PASSWORD                                                        
> -: | :---------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | 6BAFE79E0E7360094A490C0B84F2D5BA1C5A6E5C6FE1E45C2E7850966698AF29
> ```

---

## Hashing and Salting

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64894893/1509264)

If you also want to follow best practice, then you should salt the password before hashing:

```sql
CREATE TABLE client (
    id            NUMBER(10,0)
                  GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                  CONSTRAINT client__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
    password      CHAR(64)
                  NOT NULL,
    password_salt VARCHAR2(61)
                  NOT NULL
);
```

Then your trigger is:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER client_hash_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON client
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.PASSWORD = :old.PASSWORD THEN
    -- Assume things haven't changed (The chances of a hash collision are vanishingly small).
    -- Make sure the old salt is not replaced if the password hash hasn't changed.
    :new.PASSWORD_SALT := :old.PASSWORD_SALT;
  ELSE
    -- Regenerate a new salt and hash the password.
    :new.PASSWORD_SALT := DBMS_RANDOM.STRING( 'P', FLOOR( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 40, 61 ) ) );
    SELECT STANDARD_HASH ( :new.PASSWORD_SALT || RTRIM( :new.PASSWORD ), 'SHA256' )
    INTO   :new.PASSWORD
    FROM   DUAL;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

And then:

```sql
INSERT INTO client (id, password) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'BruteForce');
```

May output:

```sql
SELECT * FROM client;
```

> ```
> ID | PASSWORD                                                         | PASSWORD_SALT                              
> -: | :--------------------------------------------------------------- | :------------------------------------------
>  1 | 7465541FDF9379B2112D4E92150F594732139E94B79D0EB0247593B4E8CEB3E4 | dhj4GOC8E(xA&8b9f)j@"Y- o$G!UECR\go.SrFaZ<&
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=78a3b5b00fa34033d8fe889f16a096ed)*

Comment: This is a great answer.  One thing I'd add: since you are using a trigger (evil) and are already in PL/SQL land you should avoid the context switch of a SELECT and use dbms_crypto instead.  I will post another answer with that option.

Answer (score 2):

You use a `char` column to store a `RAW` value, returned by `standard_hash`; you should cast your `RAW` to a different type, for example by `UTL_RAW` procedures.

Also, consider that when you define a column as `char(64)` you mean that all the values will be 64 characters long, so `'BruteForce'` will be padded to 64 characters and the hash will be computed on the padded string.

If you try to add something like

```
dbms_output.put_line('Password is: "' || :NEW.password || '"');
```

to your trigger, you will see :

```
Password is: "BruteForce                                                      "
```

`Varchar2`, differently will only use the characters you need, so the hash would be computed exactly on `'BruteForce'`, that's why if you switch to `varchar2` you see a different hash result.

If you write something like

```
INSERT INTO client VALUES (DEFAULT, STANDARD_HASH('BruteForce', 'SHA256'));
```

the hash is computed not on che column content (which is a `char(64)`, thus being 64 characters long), but over the string `'BruteForce'` and the resulting hash in casted into `char(64)`.
What Oracle does is:

1. compute the hash
2. cast it to `char(64)`

The issue with the padding comes when you use the trigger because the trigger is based on the table structure, so `:NEW.password` is a `char(64)` value and the hash is computed over the already casted value, so over a string made by 64 characters.
What happens with the trigger is

1. cast the string to `char(64)`, because you are inserting in a `char(64)` column, thus padding
2. compute the hash

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I'm trying to hardcode the STANDARD_HASH it's working (when I remove the trigger): `INSERT INTO client VALUES (DEFAULT, STANDARD_HASH('BruteForce', 'SHA256'));`

Answer (score 1):

A slight change to [MT0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509264/mt0)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66331843/6068426) to remove the context switch in the trigger by using `dbms_crypto` instead of `standard_hash`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER client_hash_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON client
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.PASSWORD := rawtohex(dbms_crypto.hash(src => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(:new.PASSWORD),
                                             typ => dbms_crypto.hash_sh256));
END;
/
```