# Exception if no special char in password

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a trigger that checks certain conditions for creating an account: a password should always contain a special character.

I tried that but it doesn't work somehow and what other special characters are there?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER checking
BEFORE INSERT ON account
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
passwSpecailChar_exception EXCEPTION;
passwSpecailCharF_exception EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   IF (:NEW.Passwort)LIKE '%[: @ . , / + - ! =]%' THEN 
    RAISE passwSpecailChar_exception;
    ELSE
    RAISE passwSpecailCharF_exception;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN passwSpecailChar_exception THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Passwort acccept');
WHEN passwSpecailCharF_exception THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Password must contain at least one special character');
END ;
```

Comment: In almost all situations, you shouldn't be storing passwords as plaintext in the database to start with. By the time the password is being stored, it should have been salted and hashed and only the salt and hash are stored. So there should be no means to inspect the password at all and this would be the wrong place to enforce such a requirement (if such a requirement makes sense to begin with; modern advice is against enforcing specific character requirements in passwords)

Comment: it may not be useful. but i am just learning and these are just exercises

Comment: you can just think of it as me checking special characters in a Varchar/String

Comment: The ```LIKE``` keyword will compare a string, it does not take a regular expression. Check out ```REGEXP_LIKE```

Answer (score 2):

If your special characters are non alpha-numeric and non-whitespace characters then:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_password_special_characters
  BEFORE INSERT ON account
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE(:NEW.Passwort, '[^[:alnum:][:blank:][:space:]]' ) THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'No special characters');
  END IF;
END check_password_special_characters;
/
```

You do not want to catch the exception as you want the `INSERT` to fail and you do not want to use `DBMS_OUTPUT`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7c964feeb002fe070385486242c2bae3)*

---

As an aside, you should not be storing plain-text passwords in your database and should [hash and salt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64894893/1509264) them.

Comment: thank you, but what is alnum, blank and space

Comment: They are [POSIX character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm) in the regular expression.